# When does Alloy model initialized?

Tags: backbone.js, model, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I'm sure that Alloy collection is initialized first before the model. But I'm not sure when does this initialization starts.

1. Is it after running alloy.js, index.js, or some other .js file?
2. Is it before the first window opens, or after?
3. Is there a way to force call the initialization process so I can make sure that the initialization happens at the start of index.js?

Comment: Wondering what this has to do with backbonejs..

Comment: `Backbone.js is a lightweight MVC framework, originally designed for web applications. Alloy models are built on top of Backbone.js, taking advantage of Backbone's rich Model and Collection APIs.` I just thought maybe it can help answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize collections or models yourself.

Through js: calling `Alloy.createModel()`, `Alloy.createCollection()`, `Alloy.Models.instance()` or `Alloy.Collections.instance()`

Through markup: using `<Model />` or `<Collection />` tag

[docs here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Collection_and_Model_Objects)